# How to stretch a background image thats being inserted with JS "document.body.style.backgroundImage = url(imgsrc);"?

Tags: javascript, image

I'm making a page that has the background change based on the time of day. For instance, when hours < 12, it will set to an image like this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/morning.jpg)";
```

The image displays in the page but its a high resolution image and only shows a small section of the image, so I'm trying to stretch it. How do I reference it since it isn't an HTML element / I can't target it with CSS? At least I don't think I can?

Thanks

Comment: You can similarly use `document.body.style.backgroundSize` Try `cover` or `100%`

Comment: *" I can't target it with CSS"* Why? You can write a rule that set the size with CSS and set the background image source dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, setting the body background-size: cover worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it using CSS. Like this:

```
body {
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set background-size to "cover"

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use css property as other mentioned before.
Another way is to use [API for image Resize](https://uploadcare.com/docs/image_transformations/resize_crop/#operation-preview)